# Xcode LLVM plain C expression

Tags: c, xcode

I made a typo that looks like:

```
printf("blah-blah %d %d %d",fancy_func()),1,2;
```

I expected to get an error but for some reasons got a warning 'expression result unused' regarding '1,2' part. (Ignore missing arguments)

Also this code doesn't give any errors:

```
int x,y,z;
x,y,z;
// OR
1,2,3;
```

This doesn't look like constant or array defination.
Could someone explain why `1,2,3;` or `x,y,z;` is a valid code and what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C has a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which makes your examples syntactically legal.

Comment: So as @ScottHunter mentioned this operator is useless?

Comment: I wouldn't say "useless".  There are certain situations (e.g. a `for` loop header) where you might want to take multiple actions (say, incrementing two different variables), but the syntax requires an expression, rather than a statement or block of statements.  The comma operator allows you to do this.

Comment: Oh, i forgot about multiple statements in a 'for' loop. Thanks, you got me on track!

Answer (score 1):

The lists don't do anything; they are lists of simple expressions.  Pointless (as you have used them here), but not illegal.